# birectional pptp. access vpn client laptop from target lan

Tags: vpn, pptp

Ok I have seen this asked before but all questions are different from mine.

1. I got a local lan 192.168.100.*
2. I got a pptp server running on my NAS with ip 192.168.100.200 in my local lan
3. This pptp server assigns ip's of the form 192.168.5.* so the REMOTE client gets ip 192.168.5.1

I can fully access the TARGET 192.168.100.* network from the vpn client REMOTE laptop, what i want to do is access from my 192.68.100.24 windows local lan pc the 192.168.5.1 THE 192.168.5.1 REMOTE CLIENT WINDOWS LAPTOP !!

how can it be done ??

Via static route on the router ? via windows ip tables ?? please help me ! It cant be that hard

Thanks

Comment: you're probably missing a route. so you could run cmd as admin an run `route add 192.168.5.0/24 192.168.100.200`
this wont persist a reboot, you would need to add `-p`. 
but it would be easier to add the route to your local gateway.

Comment: it worked cheers